# What is the probability of a repeat occurring at least once in the decimal expansion of an irrational number?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

Let's take pi as an example. Pi = 3.14159... What is the probability that in the decimal expansion of pi, that there exists some number n such that that after the nth digit of the decimal expansion (beginning with 1 at first place), there is a repeat directly afterwards of all the digits up to n?

For example, if i had an irrational number which began 2.58746587462340... this would satisfy the property I mentioned, as the first 5 digits after the decimal point are immediately repeated. If I had an irrational number beginning 6.11423... this would satisfy the property too, as the first digit is repeated.

I think that the answer for an unspecified, random irrational number should be 1/9, as the probability of a repeat happening would be sum of the probabilities of the first digit immediately repeating, plus the probability of first and second, so on, to get (1/10 + 1/100 + 1/1000 + 1/10000 + ...), with a sum to infinity of 1/9.

Is this right? Obviously, to work out the value for pi, one must discard 1/10 because the first digit doesn't immediately repeat, 1/10 too, etc. So if there hasn't been a repeat in the decimals for the first few million digits, it is almost definitely not going to ever repeat it's expansion up to a certain point again?

Comment: If you had a real number chosen randomly and uniformly from an interval such as $[3,4]$ then this seems to be a correct statement about that number.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't just add $1/10+1/100+...$ because the events "first $i$ digits repeat" for $i=1,2,...$ are not disjoint. E.g. $0.111169708...$ repeats the first digit and also repeats the first two digits. So summing the probabilities like that isn't valid. This makes the problem tricky to solve.